# counting unique instances on one column depending on a condition of other column in R

Tags: r, count, unique

Assume I have the following `df`:

```
ID    X 
1    0.4
1    0.3
2    0.1
2    0.4
```

and I want to create `bins` which count the number of unique `ID`'s greater than a vector of numbers. So, I'd like my result to be something like this:

```
X    count(unique ID)
>0    1
>0.2  1
>0.4  0
```

Important to mention that all `ID`'s instances have to be included in the selected group (e.g., in my example `ID=2` has `X` values of *0.1* and *0.4*, so he'll be belonged to *>0* and not to *>0.2*.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: what's the logic behind the bins?

Comment: Use `cut` to create groups and then do a `table`

Comment: For example, think of some monthly measure over a year (for example, number of times a customer got into your store divided to the number of time he was "close" to your store (just an example)). And now you want to count the number of unique customers who are above some threshold. I think of using some `group_by` and than checking each customer separately, but I don't know how to count it in a unique way, and to `"Bin"` it

Comment: @akrun I'll try it.. just a little question... table will give me `unique` `Freq`?

Comment: Table gives the full frequency, but you can convert it to logical -> binary

Comment: @Lune3414 no. because it won't create the `bins`.. if I want to use it, I need to create another (new) field which match each customer to his `bin`